# Send email with href tag

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send an email with a link which will open an ionic app. The email is being sent but the `href` tag is being stripped. So I just get a plain Hello string. No `href`.

In the example below, Hello World is in plain text while **World** is in **bold**.

```
exports.sendNewEventEmail = functions.database.ref('/email/{pushId}/{uid}')
  .onWrite(event => {

    if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
      return;
    }

    if (!event.data.exists()) {
      return;
    }

    const mailOptions = {
      from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@example.com>`,
      to: event.data.val(),
      html: '<a href="myappname://app">Hello world ?</a><strong>World!</strong>',
      isHtml: true
    };

    mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;

    return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
      console.log('New invite email sent');
    });

  });
```

Comment: Perhaps you need a full HTML document there, rather than just one tag?

Comment: i put `<strong>Hello</strong>` and it worked. I'll try again. Just to make sure.

Comment: @DougStevenson You are right. I had to add a full document.

Answer (score 1):

set `isHtml : true` for your `mailOptions` object.

Comment: Nope ... just tried and the `href` tag was stripped.